# visual studio registering control library

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, com, registry

I am programming a Windows Form Control Library in Visual Studio 2010. I checked the box for registering as COM element. Building the solution also adds this to the registry. I am now writing a .bat script to add the output .dll to the registry on other computers. Concerning this I have the following question. Is registering this .dll using the resasm.exe the same as the registeration process used by visual studio when building the solution? I have used

```
regasm.exe "pathtodll" \tlb "pathtodll.tlb"
```

Can someone explain if this is correct or maybe tell me what visual studio 2010 exactly does when building the solution (in terms of registering dlls)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my mistake. I checked the register for com interop in the compile tab. Which appareantly means that the registering using regasm.exe is done via the following command:

```
regasm.exe pathToDll /codebase
```

I am not quite sure why and am not a registry expert. If someone can provide comments on the difference between this command and the one I used in my question (in light op registering Com elements) please do so.

As for solving my problem. This did the trick.